# How to pass a category id without a for loop and match the one with a for loop?

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I am trying to develop a menu for a friend, he opened a restaurant and I made it dynamic, I have everything working except one thing on the frontend:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Menu</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <head>
      
      <script type=text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      
    </head>
    
    <body>
      
      @foreach($category as $c)
      <div class="menuSelector">
    
        <button class="selection" id="{{ $c->name }}">
          <p>{{ $c->name }}</p>
      </div>
      @endforeach
          
      <div class="theMenu"><br><br><br> 
     
    <!-- Appetizer Menu----------------------------------------------------->                     
       <div class="appSides">
        <div class="column"> 
    
        @foreach($meal as $m)                                  
          <div class="menuItem">
            <p class="itemName">{{$m->name}}</p>
            <div class="menuItemPrice">{{$m->price}}</div>                     
          </div>          
                                                                                   
        </div>                                                                                                                                                        
       </div> 
                                                                                  
      </div>      
    </body>
    <!-- partial -->
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

In `<div class="appSides">` I want to be able to match the current category that was fetched above in order to display the products of this category, attempting to do a forloop got me all the number of categories x the number of products because I wasn't listing the categories but PHP got the number of categories, I just to be able to match the looped category so that I can display its products.

So I used jquery to do the thing and it seemed to work with static content but not with dynamic content(Content passed from the Models and Controllers).

PS: If there is any other way to display the products, I would gladly be happy to do it!

Thank you so much for the help,

Elias,

Comment: So you are saying that the ```$meal``` contains all the categories and you want to be able to extract all the product specific category from ```$meal``` to ```$m``` right?

Comment: Exactly, I have a categories table and a meals table, they are connected via primary keys, the tables are built on MySQL, I want to be able to display the category in the `<div class="menuSelector">` and display the products below related to this category, in the backend it is very easy but on the frontend it is causing me some trouble due to complex design

Comment: Show your controller code, please. If your tables are connected via primary keys then it should be more than easy to do this.

Comment: It doesn't look complex though. Please share your controller code so I can have a better understanding.